# Can you identify this dead bug?

Tags: species-identification

I found this bug in the kitchen and already killed it. It's in austria area. Can someone tell me if it's dangerous?

[image: bug]

Comment: Welcome. Could you give us some idea of scale, tell us what you found it on or near, was it eating anything?

Comment: Photos of the other side?

Comment: Looks like an Ectobius_vittiventris, a so called ['Bernstein Waldschabe'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ectobius_vittiventris) which is recently [invading Austria](https://kurier.at/wissen/kakerlaken-doppelgaenger-was-es-mit-der-invasion-der-bernstein-waldschabe-auf-sich-hat/400606175). I might be extending this comment to an answer once I have sufficient time on my hands to provide sources and proove.. Greetings from Vienna, we have lots of them too in the surounding suburbs. It feeds on decomposing plant material, so don't worry it's not dangerous to humans - rather the other way around ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like an [Ectobius_vittiventris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ectobius_vittiventris), a so called 'Bernstein Waldschabe' or 'amber wood cockroach' in English, which is 'recently' [invading Austria and Southern Germany](https://kurier.at/wissen/kakerlaken-doppelgaenger-was-es-mit-der-invasion-der-bernstein-waldschabe-auf-sich-hat/400606175), especially in hot and dry summers.

[image]

Image info: Author: Amada44, Licensed: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/en:GNU_Free_Documentation_License

In size, shape and color, the amber forest cockroach is very similar to the German cockroach [Blattella germanica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_cockroach), which is feared as a hygiene pest and is usually controlled. The most striking difference is the **uniform brown pronotum** in the amber forest cockroach, which in the **German cockroach has two dark longitudinal stripes**.

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ectobius_vittiventris)

From Wikipedia:

> It is a species of wood cockroach originally from southern Europe . It is completely harmless to humans and does not appear as a storage pest, as it only feeds on decomposing plant material and perishes within a few days in human dwellings due to a lack of food. Its original range is south of the Alps, but this species seems to have established itself permanently north of the Alps and in southern Germany.

From Wikipedia:

> The natural habitat of the amber forest cockroach is outdoors in low bushes and in gardens under pots. It feeds on decomposing plant material. Warm, dry summers can encourage mass reproduction. Then the probability is high that the animals can also be found in apartments.

Since it feeds on decomposing plants it's not dangerous to humans - rather the other way around ;)